# Software that makes an image pop when i click on a certain location

Tags: images, mouse

I have a picture (image file) of a line map(from autocad), and a need to put put real photos on a certian location of a map. Like this example but for a bigger map 
[image: See image] or like google maps  [image: See image]

Comment: On what OS should it run? What is your price margin? What formats are relevant (input/output), what shall be used to *view* the results (assuming you're asking for software to *create* them)?

Comment: I'am running Windows 7, any price if free better, jpeg, yes i need a software that shows the image

Comment: You're aware that JPEG isn't inter-active – so your "click here to show" cannot work with them, and it thus wouldn't be suitable as output format? AFAIK there's eg. [SVG supporting that](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html) – and probably also has a lot of viewers available.

Comment: You could combine HTML / JavaScript and your image. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map